# geomesa ingest into hbase error

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, geomesa

when I ingest sample data into hbase following the geomesa manual, this error is thrown:

> The following variables were not loaded from
>   /media/svr3/geomesa/geomesa-hbase_2.11-1.3.4/conf/geomesa-env.sh due
>   to an existing configuration.
>       HADOOP_HOME, 
>       HADOOP_CONF_DIR, 
>       HADOOP_COMMON_HOME, 
>       HADOOP_HDFS_HOME, 
>       YARN_HOME, 
>       HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME, 
>       ZOOKEEPER_HOME
>       Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Dgeomesa.hbase.coprocessor.path=hdfs://hbase/lib/geomesa-hbase-distributed-runtime_2.11-1.3.4.jar
>       Apr 19, 2018 8:19:28 AM org.geotools.data.DataAccessFinder getDataStore

```
  WARNING: HBase (GeoMesa) should be used, but could not connect
>         java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:3140)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory.checkClusterAvailability(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:99)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory.org$locationtech$geomesa$hbase$data$HBaseDataStoreFactory$$globalConnection$lzycompute(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:44)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory.org$locationtech$geomesa$hbase$data$HBaseDataStoreFactory$$globalConnection(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:41)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory$$anonfun$2.apply(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:61)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory$$anonfun$2.apply(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:61)
>                 at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:61)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:36)
>                 at org.geotools.data.DataAccessFinder.getDataStore(DataAccessFinder.java:130)
>                 at org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(DataStoreFinder.java:89)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.AbstractIngest.<init>(AbstractIngest.scala:72)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.ConverterIngest.<init>(ConverterIngest.scala:43)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.IngestCommand$class.createConverterIngest(IngestCommand.scala:64)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.tools.ingest.HBaseIngestCommand.createConverterIngest(HBaseIngestCommand.scala:21)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.IngestCommand$class.execute(IngestCommand.scala:57)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.tools.ingest.HBaseIngestCommand.execute(HBaseIngestCommand.scala:21)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.Runner$class.main(Runner.scala:28)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.tools.HBaseRunner$.main(HBaseRunner.scala:21)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.tools.HBaseRunner.main(HBaseRunner.scala)
>         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>                 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>                 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
>                 ... 22 more
>         Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.tracing.TraceUtils.wrapHadoopConf(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)Lorg/apache/htrace/core/HTraceConfiguration;
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsTracer.get(FsTracer.java:42)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:696)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:680)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:158)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.initTempDir(DynamicClassLoader.java:120)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.<init>(DynamicClassLoader.java:98)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.<clinit>(ProtobufUtil.java:244)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterId.parseFrom(ClusterId.java:64)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:75)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:905)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:648)
>                 ... 27 more
>         
>  ERROR java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:3140)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory.checkClusterAvailability(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:99)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory.org$locationtech$geomesa$hbase$data$HBaseDataStoreFactory$$globalConnection$lzycompute(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:44)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory.org$locationtech$geomesa$hbase$data$HBaseDataStoreFactory$$globalConnection(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:41)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory$$anonfun$2.apply(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:61)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory$$anonfun$2.apply(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:61)
>                 at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:61)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.data.HBaseDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(HBaseDataStoreFactory.scala:36)
>                 at org.geotools.data.DataAccessFinder.getDataStore(DataAccessFinder.java:130)
>                 at org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(DataStoreFinder.java:89)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.AbstractIngest.<init>(AbstractIngest.scala:72)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.ConverterIngest.<init>(ConverterIngest.scala:43)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.IngestCommand$class.createConverterIngest(IngestCommand.scala:64)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.tools.ingest.HBaseIngestCommand.createConverterIngest(HBaseIngestCommand.scala:21)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.IngestCommand$class.execute(IngestCommand.scala:57)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.tools.ingest.HBaseIngestCommand.execute(HBaseIngestCommand.scala:21)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.Runner$class.main(Runner.scala:28)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.tools.HBaseRunner$.main(HBaseRunner.scala:21)
>                 at org.locationtech.geomesa.hbase.tools.HBaseRunner.main(HBaseRunner.scala)
>         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>                 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>                 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
>                 ... 22 more
>         Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.tracing.TraceUtils.wrapHadoopConf(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)Lorg/apache/htrace/core/HTraceConfiguration;
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsTracer.get(FsTracer.java:42)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:696)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:680)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:158)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.initTempDir(DynamicClassLoader.java:120)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.<init>(DynamicClassLoader.java:98)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.<clinit>(ProtobufUtil.java:244)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterId.parseFrom(ClusterId.java:64)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:75)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:905)
>                 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:648)
>                 ... 27 more
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What version of hadoop are you using? It appears to be incompatible. Generally, when you get a `NoSuchMethodError`, it indicates a classpath issue.